# Thousand separator for read-only input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to implement a thousand space separator in a ReadOnly input type number, but when trying to do so, it doesn't seem to be working and I can only write three numbers, and then the whole thing disappears.

#### Code

```html
<input
  type="number"
  onChange={props.onInputChange}
  value={props.value ? props.value : 0}
  min={props.min}
  max={props.max}
  readOnly="readonly"
 />
```

```javascript
export const priceFormatterSpace = (price) => {
  return price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
};
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see this called, and why would a readonly ever onChange?

Comment: the onChange changes the value of the input, I only need to implement thousands separators on the value.

Comment: Can you show what is written in your fuction `onInputChange`

Comment: The problem is that you have **number** input element but you're trying to insert a **string**.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You have to change your input to `type="text"` and first remove non-numeric characters then format the digits. You can only have a limited set of characters in input fields that are `type="number"`. Chrome only allows one period or comma per value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  // Format value by the thousands. Add a comma between
  const numberWithCommas = (num) => {
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
 
  // Remove non-numeric characters from input
  const removeNonNumeric = (num) => {
    return num.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  }

  // Handle user typing into the input 
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = numberWithCommas(removeNonNumeric(e.target.value))

    setValue(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
  );
}
```